# Automatically Scroll down using php

Tags: php

hi can anyone help me with this problem: i have a php page which has a lot of information in iy. i want to do something like in wikipedia. in wikipedia the table of contents are all links. so if the user decided not to scroll down just to read the topic, the user will just rely on the links on the table of contents and when the user clicks it, the page will automatically scroll itself and will stop on that topic. i wanna do something like that in my php page. can anyone help me? kindly show me a sample code. thanks

Comment: You mean something like this http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations ?

Answer (score 4):

Link using a [fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/intro.html#h-2.1.2).

```
<a href="#foo">Foo</a>

<div id="foo">
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p> yada yada </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is simple HTML

```
<a href="#link_targets">Link Targets</a>

..
..
<div id="link_targets">
// here is your content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do something like that on your PHP page.
Because user never sees your PHP page, but rather HTML page generated by your PHP script.

So, you can use HTML tags to scroll something.
You can always see any HTML tag in the page source. So - just find out what which tag is used in wikipedia and use the same in your HTML.